# Downloading HTML Content

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsurl, nsurlsession

I'm trying to get the html of a web page with this code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.handasaim.co.il/news.asp")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    (data, response, error) in
    if error == nil {
        var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(urlContent)
     }
}

 task.resume()
```

I think the problem is that the url ending is .asp because when I tried it with a different url it worked.

What's the problem?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: There is no error, it just gives a nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage you've specified does not use UTF8 encoding. If you'll specify the correct encoding when trying to create NSString from data - it will work.

```
var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
```

Comment: To fix this:

1.  Grab the textEncodingName property of the response object to get the name of the correct text encoding.
2.  Call the CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding function to convert that string to a CFString encoding.
3.  Call the CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding function to convert the CFString encoding to an NSString encoding.
4.  Pass that as the encoding parameter when creating the string.